# HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean with Spring Boot 1.5 Release

Tags: hibernate, sessionfactory

We can't upgrade to Spring Boot **1.5** Release (from 1.4.4).
It gives us an error "org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread".
We use HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean to get SessionFactory for our legacy hibernate code and it's not working anymore.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks.